# Reason for ExtractMethodCodeRefactoringProvider encountered an error and has been disabled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting this error, when I'm trying to extract the method from code by using right-click on a selected code(Quick Actions and Refactoring) or `Ctrl + .`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm able to refactor for other projects in a different solution. My solution has multiple projects, it's not working on all the projects under this solution.

I tried the same thing using Visual Studio 2010, this is working fine with a solution.

It's showing this error only in Visual Studio 2015.

so is this a bug in Visual Studio 2015? or I need to make some settings in Visual Studio or in code, solution or projects?, I never saw this error before with Studio 2015.

[image: Error]

FYI: It's not a compilation error, It's just a warning, It's not stopping me to run the application or debug.

Comment: Only time I ever had that there was a compile error somewhere else

Comment: Its not compilation error, its just a warning, thanks for you comment. I have updated my question.

Comment: Getting in VS 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug and it is now fixed (currently pending release)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24463/extractmethodcoderefactoringprovider-encountered-a-2.html

Comment: 15.9.1 now and I've been getting this message all year.

Comment: In VS2019 (16.1.3) as well

Comment: In 16.1.6 same mumbo jumbo

Comment: I am still getting this error message in VS Community 2019

Comment: I am too in Visual Studio Community 2019 v. 16.11.94.52318

Answer (score 1):

The issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17165) and be released in VS 15.3.

HTH

Comment: I'm getting it in 15.9.8

Comment: me too, VS 2017 (v 15.9.7)

Comment: I'm getting this warning too, in VS 2017 (v 15.9.19)

Answer (score 0):

> #### A fix for this issue has been released (v 16.0)

[Install the recent release from here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)