# Visual Studio - "restore" code refactoring error in infobar

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, roslyn

I have VS 2017 and in debug encountered a message like this (not my code, had to find it in the internet as i don't have this message any longer)
[image]

I've pressed "Enable" and the message has disappeared, but now it affects my debugging as simple assignment operation `var a = "something"` throws null reference exceptions <del>and my code fails</del>, is there any way to revert the "Enable" action and rollback the changes made by it?

**UPD 1:**
I tried devenv reset, updating and reinstalling vs, didn't fix the issue

**UPD 2:**
the issue seems to be more of a cosmetic origin, calling a method with a variable that threw an exception as one of the parameters results in a correct value being passed to the called method

Comment: You seem not to be the only one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608458/reason-for-extractmethodcoderefactoringprovider-encountered-an-error-and-has-bee

Comment: There are multiple reports of this exact issue, but i'm ok with rolling back and just getting the error instead of NRE in variable, so slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...is there any way to revert the "Enable" action..."

Disabling Extensions can happen from the Tools -> Extensions and Updates window.

[image]

As far as being able to rollback changes made by it, make sure Visual Studio is not synchronizing settings, and do a full uninstall/reinstall.

Synchronization settings are outlined [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio#side-by-side-synchronized-settings)

In order to provide more help, I would need to know what extensions are installed.