# Visual Studio 2019 Encounted an Error and has been disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Today I installed **Visual Studio 201**9 on my laptop and run a few code then I got this error :

[image: Error]

And this is the Stack Trace :

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Roslyn.Utilities.PathUtilities.PathsEqual(String path1,String path2)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeRefactorings.SyncNamespace.AbstractSyncNamespaceCodeRefactoringProvider`3.State.IsDocumentPathRootedInProjectFolder(Document document)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeRefactorings.SyncNamespace.AbstractSyncNamespaceCodeRefactoringProvider`3.State.CreateAsync[TNamespaceDeclarationSyntax,TCompilationUnitSyntax,TMemberDeclarationSyntax](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeRefactorings.SyncNamespace.AbstractSyncNamespaceCodeRefactoringProvider`3.ComputeRefactoringsAsync[TNamespaceDeclarationSyntax,TCompilationUnitSyntax,TMemberDeclarationSyntax](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeRefactorings.CodeRefactoringService.GetRefactoringFromProviderAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I would really appreciate any help on what this means
when I got this error I clicked `Enable` and restarted visual studio and it works fine now, But I would like to know why I got this error and how I can avoid it.

**EDIT:** After I made the post I tried to run my code again (the code dosen't have any errors) but vs breaks everytime imgur.com/tNrkE6l is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Don't worry about those, just click on "Enable". Those are just errors from Visual Studio itself, not your code.

Comment: Thank You, for further clarification : does visual studio disable features if it encounters a problem ?

Comment: Yes, but normally those are minimal features and can be enabled again just by clicking "Enable" -> no need to restart VS

Comment: This breaks [repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608458/reason-for-extractmethodcoderefactoringprovider-encountered-an-error-and-has-bee), VS2019 version 16.11 had yet another fix for it (but specific to asp.net).  Don't worry about it.

Comment: After I made the post I tried to run my code again (the code dosen't have any errors) but vs breaks everytime https://imgur.com/tNrkE6l

is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting my current project and creating a new one, it fixed all the errors,
code runs just fine now.